# Visual Studio Code: Export .jar giving me no valid classpath found in the export jar configuration

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, export, executable-jar

I cant export my JAR file, its just a simples ''hello world'' code and I want to export it as a JAR file. But it gives me an error I cant figure out how to solve. Pls look at my step by step trying to create a jar file

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmhfe.png)

[Clicking on Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVPKM.png)

[Selecting workspace and code but it gives me that error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibMPy.png)

[My configure classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/214Ju.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the parent folder containing all languages, you should open the **Java** project's folder as a workspace.

Alternatively you can export the **jar** file using the `jar` command. E.g:

```
jar cf App.jar -C classes
```

Comment: The error still happens if only my java program folder is open. That code gives me this error

 jar : The term 'jar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ jar cf App.jar -C classes
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (jar:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Have the jdk and java extensions installed according to [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial)?